# How to Build Mobile Application for Image Recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, image-classification

I want to write an application on (Android) phone for image recognition. The (Keras) model itself is written and trained on a desktop machine and works satisfactorily with standard images. However, I have no experience with app programing so I have no clue how to write an app itself which could utilize the model.

The purpose is to use the mobile camera for seeking the object; have a big button to shot an image; have the image classified and display the output label as text. No need for any sophisticated outlook. I can write programs in Python.

Is there any handy framework that could be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to use [kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) for Python. It has an active community and there is also a book on this topic [*Practical Computer Vision Applications Using Deep Learning with CNNs With Detailed Examples in Python Using TensorFlow and Kivy*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484241665). Kivy is very easy for newbies and you can develop multiplatform applications (Windows, iOs, Android).